# How can i close an activity with the back button of device?

Tags: android

i want to close an activity with the back button of my device... any suggestion???

Comment: What device? A C64? A traffic light? A microwave?

Answer (score 4):

The current activity is automatically "closed" (a.k.a., destroyed) by the BACK button on your device.

Comment: Is it? Wouldn't it be just hanging around for you to maybe start it again? Like activities should in Android? Do you have a reference for this? It's probably stopped or paused, yes, but destroyed? I'd say not?

Comment: @Nanne: "Is it?". Yes. "Wouldn't it be just hanging around for you to maybe start it again?" No. "Like activities should in Android?" You are mistaken. "Do you have a reference for this?" http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#actlife (in addition to the three books on Android application development that I wrote) "It's probably stopped or paused, yes, but destroyed? I'd say not?" -- you are mistaken. The BACK button by default triggers `finish()`, which destroys the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Register an KeyListener and implement [OnKey][1].
There check if the back button is pressed. If the back button is pressed, call the [OnStop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29) method.

But be aware that this could violate the lifecycle principle in Android

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey(android.view.View, int, android.view.KeyEvent)

Comment: Activities should *not* be calling lifecycle methods themselves.

Comment: Yes. That's why I added the warning that this violates the lifecycle principle.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Android's philosophy is to not include an explicit exit functionality. If you're handling resources properly, i.e. activating them during the `Resume()` and releasing them during the `Pause()` event, then you're just fine. Your activity will stay there and the system will decide on whether to remove it or to recycle it in case it comes to the foreground again later on.

Reto Meier wrote an interesting article about whether to include exit buttons/functionalities:
http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html

As also Roman Guy said in his popular [ListView](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) talk at I/O2010: Don't try to be smarter than the system but just aim to use it the way it is intended, because you most probably make the situation worse than better. These guys are putting a lot of effort in making things perform more optimal with each new release of the OS.